# Dynamics CRM 2011 set field value in plug-in using VB

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am brand new to Crm. I need to run a plug-in that will execute on Contact entity creation. It needs to look at the GUID of the Contact and set a field on the Contact form to that value, so it can be referenced in a Dialog.  I am coding in VB.

Can someone show me some sample code in VB?

Answer (score 2):

The CRM SDK had code samples in in both C# and VB. You will need it for your development in any case so I suggest you start looking there.

The SDK can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004).

Comment: Thank you. I had already downloaded the SDK but the code samples I've found are giving me errors. I am trying to see what is wrong environmentally.  I don't understand why my inquiry would be closed by the administrators - others have asked for code examples.

Comment: Perhaps you'd have been better of posting the code with the error you were receiving - just an idea.